# Regex to get array from content?

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

I'm calling a webpage using the Request library, and I am storing the response body as a javascript variable.  The response body consists of the HTML of the page.  Ignore the fact that this is javascript, I cannot edit the code below.  Think of it as a text string I need to perform regex on.

Below is a snippet of the response body, however I need to perform some regex to extract the contents of the `sales_rank` array.

So far I have the below, but I am struggling to know where to go next:

`\sales_ranks = \[()/g`

```
(function() {
            var chart = $(document).find('#flot-chart'),
                sales_ranks = [
                                                [1498101635000, 0],
                                                [1498187306000, 0],
                                                [1498274424000, 0],
                                                [1498360866000, 0],
                                                [1498447842000, 0],
                                                [1498534646000, 0],
                                                [1498620767000, 0],
                                                [1498706919000, 0],
                                                [1498793120000, 259312],
                                                [1498879764000, 490981],
                                                [1498965369000, 633892],
                                                [1499052315000, 792398],
                                                [1499138463000, 215732],
                                                [1499225377000, 435596],
                                                [1499311360000, 110890],
                                                [1499398681000, 299988],
                                                [1499484963000, 194321],
                                                [1499571308000, 184823],
                                                [1499657546000, 282991],
                                                [1499744175000, 96775],
                                                [1499830311000, 399822],
                                                [1499916360000, 483213],
                                                [1500002994000, 284743],
                                                [1500089388000, 163017],
                                                [1500175564000, 101008],
                                                [1500261919000, 131600],
                                                [1500349007000, 60496],
                                                [1500434715000, 134451],
                                                [1500521280000, 151996],
                                                [1500607500000, 145079],
                                        ]
```

If anyone know how to do this, it'd be much appreciated if you could help.  Alternatively, if you know of a way to extract the array when storing the html in a javascript variable, that could also work

Comment: sales_ranks already looks like regular array. Can you provide raw data and what do you want to see on finish?

Comment: Regex is used to search in text (i.e. string). For arrays, you can use loops or array methods. That should be easy enough, but if you face a problem, edit your question and explain the issue and what you want to achieve, so we can help you.

Comment: I've just updated my question, perhaps I wasn't clear enough.  I am saving the HTML as a javascript variable, because it is the response from a GET request.  I don't have direct access to the code that is being loaded above

Comment: How to do what? Not at all clear what is going on here

Comment: Updated question again to add some clarity

Comment: You really need to learn how to ask a question. The code you posted has nothing to do with the question, your question is unclear, and what you want to achieve is vague. How do you expect us to help you, if you don't provide us with the required info? We're not wizards here.

Comment: your big array - is data thay you already extracted, is not it? and you want to find something in array sales_ranks. Am I correct?

Comment: @RacilHilan The code posted is an extract of the response body when using the Request lib.  Since I cannot directly access this code since it's stored in a variable, the only way I can think to access what I need is to use Regex on it.  Forget the fact that it is javascript, just think of it as a text string

Comment: ok, whole your code is just text. right?

Comment: @qiAlex For the sake of this question, yes :)

Comment: great! and what do you want to get from it? numbers?

Comment: @qiAlex So I need everything from [1498101635000, 0] through to [1500607500000, 145079].  Those numbers will change, so really its everything inbetween the text ```sales_rank = [ <anything here> ]```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your given text, following regex should work:

```
/\bsales_ranks\s*=\s*\[(?:\s*\[[^\]]+\],)+\s*\]/ig
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/MnCCIV/1)

**RegEx Breakup:**

- `\b` : assert word boundary
- `sales_ranks` : match literal `sales_ranks`
- `\s*=\s*` : match `=` surrounded by whitespaces on both sides
- `\[` : match literal `[`
- `(?:` : start non-capturing group

  - `\s*\[[^\]]+\],` : match whitespaces followed by `[...],` elements
- `)+` : end non-capturing group. `+` means match all of the inner elements
- `\s*` : match 0 or more whitespaces
- `\]` : match last closing `]`

Comment: Thanks.  This appears to work, however ```body.match(/\bsales_ranks\s*=\s*\[(?:\s*\[[^\]]+\],)+\s*\]/)[0];``` appears to also include the ```sales_rank = [``` part.  Is there a way to just take the contents?

Comment: I think the regex is including the sales_rank = [ as part of the group for some reason.  Even though regex101 seems to show group 1, it doesn't appear when performing my javascript match

Comment: [Check this demo and examine group #1](https://regex101.com/r/MnCCIV/2)

Comment: Yeah I can see group 1 in the demo, however if I log this this ```body.match(/\bsales_ranks\s*=\s*\[(?:\s*\[[^\]]+\],)+\s*\]/ig)``` I get the this: https://pastebin.com/bQaWfNLT

Comment: Sorry, copied the wrong regex in.  I'm using that regex and the outcome is still the same

Comment: If you can reproduce a JSFiddle or regex101 demo I can certainly look into that.

Comment: Ah it should be: `var res = (body.match(/\bsales_ranks\s*=\s*\[((?:\s*\[[^\]]+\],)+)\s*\]/i) || ['', ''])[1];` or [See your updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7w478v0q/1/)

Comment: Ah thats perfect!  Thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

I suck at regex so my approach is to split at `salesrank =` and walk through all the `[]` braces until find the last one

```js
var str = getText().split('sales_ranks =')[1].trim(),
  openBraces = false,
  lastBraceIndex;
for (var i = 1; i < str.length; i++) {
  if (str[i] == '[') {
    openBraces = true;
  } else if (str[i] == ']') {
    if (openBraces) {
      openBraces = false
    } else {
      lastBraceIndex = i;
      break;
    }
  }
}
var json = str.slice(0, lastBraceIndex + 1)

// parse json to show valid array returned
console.log(JSON.parse(json))



function getText() {

  return `

(function() {
    var chart = $(document).find('#flot-chart'),
      sales_ranks = [
        [1498101635000, 0],
        [1498187306000, 0],
        [1498274424000, 0],
        [1498360866000, 0],
        [1498447842000, 0],
        [1498534646000, 0],
        [1498620767000, 0],
        [1498706919000, 0],
        [1498793120000, 259312],
        [1498879764000, 490981],
        [1498965369000, 633892],
        [1499052315000, 792398],
        [1499138463000, 215732],
        [1499225377000, 435596],
        [1499311360000, 110890],
        [1499398681000, 299988],
        [1499484963000, 194321],
        [1499571308000, 184823],
        [1499657546000, 282991],
        [1499744175000, 96775],
        [1499830311000, 399822],
        [1499916360000, 483213],
        [1500002994000, 284743],
        [1500089388000, 163017],
        [1500175564000, 101008],
        [1500261919000, 131600],
        [1500349007000, 60496],
        [1500434715000, 134451],
        [1500521280000, 151996],
        [1500607500000, 145079]
      ];

      var someotherarray =[1,2,3,4];
  }();
  
  `

}
```

Note that the last trailing comma in your example breaks json parsing. Removed from this example

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
var result = YOUR_VARIABLE.match(/sales_ranks\s*=\s*\[(.|\n|\r)*?\s+\]/gmi)[0];
```

Comment: Thanks.  This also works but I have the same issue as anubhava's response, whereby the result also includes the ```sales_rank = [``` part, and there don't appear to be any other groups